# Why am I unable to insert a document into my Elasticsearch index via a Firebase Cloud function?

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to insert a document into my Elasticsearch index via a Firebase Cloud Function but I keep getting the following error:

```
{ Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms
    at 
/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:355:15
    at Timeout.<anonymous> 
(/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:384:7)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
  status: undefined,
  displayName: 'RequestTimeout',
  message: 'Request Timeout after 30000ms',
  body: undefined }
```

but when I run the same code snippet I'm using on a local server instance I have no issues inserting the document.

```
const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    hosts: ['http://******:**********@ipaddress:port']
});

client.index({
    index: 'csv',
    type: 'default',
    body: {
      message: 'hi'
    }
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The cloud function is as follows:

```
const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    hosts: ['http://******:**********@ipaddress:port']
});

exports.createElasticEntry = functions.firestore
    .document('listings/{listingId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        client.index({
            index: 'csv',
            type: 'default',
            body: {
              message: 'hi'
            }
        })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: Which billing plan is your function on?  Also, you're not returning a promise that's resolved when the async work from `client.index()` is complete.

Comment: @Doug's comment makes sense, although the timeout is thrown from the ES client code, which means that it has trouble reaching the ES server. Can you make sure that your ES server is reachable from wherever the cloud function is running?

Comment: Just the free billing plan. Oh okay, how would I resolve it if that is the case?

I'm not 100% sure, it seems to be reachable from different areas in my city though.

Comment: Yes it is reachable from where the cloud function is running, was purely due to the pricing plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Functions, with the free Spark plan, you can't make outgoing connections to services that are not fully controlled and managed by Google.  This is to prevent abuse.

If you want to connect to external services, you will need to upgrade to a paid plan.